# Search in one2many field wrong behavior odoo

Tags: python, odoo, searchview

In product template, I have defined this structure to be able of searching by model and range of application years.

In this example, using the search box,typing SENTRA as model paramater AND 1998 as year of application, should not bring any record, but it does.

It seems like my search is done fetching all my one2many field and not only the first row.

[image: application data odoo]

Here is the code:

```
<field string="Modelo" name="application_data_product_template_ids" filter_domain="[('application_data_product_template_ids.model', 'ilike',self)]"/>
<field name="date_search" />

def _search_year(self, cr, uid, obj, name, args, context):
    x = [('application_data_product_template_ids.date_beg', '<=', args[0][2]), ('application_data_product_template_ids.dateend', '>=', args[0][2])]
    res = self.search(cr, uid, x, context=context)
    return [('id', 'in', res)]
```

Is there a way to do this search correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `separator` between search fields, otherwise it **OR**s them:

```
<field string="Modelo" name="application_data_product_template_ids" .../>
<separator/>
<field name="date_search" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I got the same result, I still think the problem is that it doesn't search in the row in which found the first paramater(Model in this case), could it be other reason?